# Interesting convex function inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, convex-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $f:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb R$ a convex function. Prove that:

$$20\int^3_0 f(x)\,dx + 10\int^6_0 f(x)\,dx \ge 12 \int^5_0 f(x)\,dx + 15 \int^4_0 f(x)\,dx$$
I tried to use the Newton-Leibniz formula but I did not get to any relevant point.

Comment: we could rewrite it as to prove $$10(2F(3)+F(6))\ge 3(4F(5)+5F(4))$$ where $F'''(x)>0$ i  dont see anything to do with this but the symmetery is definitely evident

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore .... $f'' > 0$ implies convex, but not conversely.  Convex functions need not be differentiable.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh i guess that was wrong,just wanted to point out the symmmetry /pattern ,thats all thansk for correcting me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint : Apply the inequality $$f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$
with $x=3u$, $y=6u$, $t_1=1/3$ and also $t_2=2/3$. Then add, and integrate from $0$ to $1$, change the variables, and to finish multiply by $60$.

Comment: Thank you very much!